# Why don't people use <CFLOGIN>?

Tags: coldfusion, cflogin

Why don't people use CFLOGIN?  I remember having problem with it with CF7 some months ago, but I couldn't remember what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use cflogin all the time and it works great.  It can be a little tricky to get working the way you like, but the benefits are huge.  Being able to fine tune your application with user roles takes care of the bulk of my rights based customization.  There used to be some issues with session management that made it difficult to work with.  Turning on j2ee sessions seems to make most of those issues go away.

Some of the popular frameworks are not compatible with cflogin, so that might be one reason you don't see a lot of it.  They tend to have their own approach to securing application features.

I think a lot of people get frustrated with it because it is a little quirky and they give up on it.  Others have more complicated security needs that aren't addressed completely by cflogin, so they wind up writing their own system.  Specifically, there isn't an easy way to deal with rights by content asset.

Comment: What are the "issues with session management"?  Do you remember?

Comment: The issues I vaguely remember were that closing out all of your browsers would not terminate your authentication if you didn't use j2ee sessions and that on high volume sites (again, without j2ee sessions), login credentials could be hijacked when a cfid was reused.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I've had is with roles in CF8.  It's brilliantly implemented, and a little cruel that it doesn't work as it quite should.  Maybe in CF9.

In any event, building your own roles based system (assign the user a session variable with a comma separated list of access levels that the system can check against) isn't too hard to do and I got over it.

The one nice thing about cfLogin that is probably still worth using is how it ties into the Server monitor to see how many people are logged in, etc.

The point above about using the jsession is true, it's worth doing in all cf apps.  One of the best things I dragged myself through to get working how I wanted it.

Comment: I can't get it to work with NTLM authentication *at all* (on CF7 anyway). FWIW, it just does not work the way it is advertised. I usually fake it into running correctly, because I want to use role-based security, but the tag itself is simply broken.

Answer (score 2):

**CFLogin is not used for 3 reasons.**

**First**, it's a little touchy, a little strange, and doesn't work how many would think. You put some code here, and if a user isn't logged in it runs it... that's just odd, you know? It didn't help that there were some bugs early on, either.

**Second**, while it has the basic required security features for a web application, it doesn't go any further. You can't really extend it easily. Who's to say that's how everybody wants it?

**Third**, and most realistically, it's because people have already solved that problem. The problem area of securing an application, authentication and authorization has been thought out in the community long enough and most people know how to just do it. CFLogin is reinventing the door. It is too little, too late.

Now, that's not to say that no one uses it. I personally have used it a few times with basic success, but no reason to ring a bell. For most of my applications, it makes more sense to not use CFLogin. The problem domains are this way or that, and CFLogin doesn't always solve it in the most intelligent way.

Answer (score 2):

Do keep in mind that CFLOGIN has a catch with Basic HTTP Auth where it can continue to send its UserID and Password even after you have called CFLOGOUT.

I know this has driven some advanced users away from it.

Here is an excerpt from [LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00001182.htm)

> Caution: If you use web server-based
>   authentication or any form
>   authentication that uses a Basic HTTP
>   Authorization header, the browser
>   continues to send the authentication
>   information to your application until
>   the user closes the browser, or in
>   some cases, all open browser windows.
>   As a result, after the user logs out
>   and your application uses the cflogout
>   tag, until the browser closes, the
>   cflogin structure in the cflogin tag
>   will contain the logged-out user's
>   UserID and password. If a user logs
>   out and does not close the browser,
>   another user might access pages with
>   the first user's login.

Comment: Just realized, this is not CFLOGIN's fault.  This is a common problem with HTTP Basic Authentication, search stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

In my case (suppose for some other people too) the main reason is moving from other platform, say PHP. I mean that I've *already* got some knowledge and habits in ACL development and started using them in CF.

I know how to make it handy for user, flexible for developer and secure and don't *really need* to switch to cflogin.

Sometimes the same happens with other stuff, say in most cases I prefer to implement client-side validation using own JS instead of using cfform/cfinput.

Answer (score -2):

Because it (still!) has serious bugs, like this one:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/8/7/Watch-out-for-this-CFLOGIN-Bug

Comment: read the comment I posted there.  "The colon in URL should have been encoded to %3A, then the cflogin.password works!"