# How secure is my site to intruders with CFLOGIN

Tags: coldfusion, cflogin

How secure is my site to intruders with CFLOGIN, is there a way to bypass the username and password form?
the form is called from the application.cfc

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this Question and follow the links...

[Why don't people use <CFLOGIN>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604909/why-dont-people-use-cflogin)

The short answer is that it depends a lot on how you implement the tag. Nothing is 100% secure but CFLOGIN mostly works and unless you know CF well enough to roll your own more robust version it is a useful tag.