# Why does cfloginuser require a password attribute? What is it used for?

Tags: coldfusion, cflogin

> "Its not stated here what the password
>   field is used for, or why it is
>   required. I was told by an Adobe
>   employee at CFUnited 2008 that it was
>   used to recreate the login in
>   clustered environments. An explanation
>   of this process might be useful."
>   - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_j-l_08.html

So actually why does `<cfloginuser>` require a password attribute??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password is used for the base64 string

see: [CFLogin Security Considerations](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/735.cfm)

But why is the password needed for the base64 string?  I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

cfloginuser is used in combination with cflogin to log a user into your application.  You use either a form submission with username and password values, basic authentication or NTLM authentication.  All of these require a username and password.

Comment: but usually the code inside of cflogin will take care of authenticating the user through #flogin.name# and #cflogin.password#, why do I need to store the password at cfloginuser (i.e. after I've authenticated the user)?

Comment: yeah, cflogin doesn't actually perform the authentication.  it just tells the application about the user.

Comment: ya, so... why does cfloginuser requires the password exactly?  AFAIK it still works fine if I only pass in an empty string for every user, thx

Comment: the better question is why are you using it?  it has its quirks, and once you move past very basic authentication and security you reach its limits very quickly.  ultimately, more often than not, you end up refactoring to a custom solution.  Its easy enough to implement a basic security system that matches cflogin's functionality, so rather than build it twice, why not build it yourself the first time and allow yourself room for future growth.

Comment: @Sean What are the 'quirks'?  I have not experienced them so far.  I even asked the question some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604909/why-dont-people-use-cflogin and the only 'quirks' regarding cannot logout a HTTP basic authentication is busted.

Comment: Anyway, this answer does not really answers my question.

Comment: @Henry Search Ray's blog (http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/) for his many issues trying to use cflogin in his OSS apps.  Most recently: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/8/7/Watch-out-for-this-CFLOGIN-Bug

Comment: The 'bug' in that post is not actually a bug!  The colon in URL should have been encoded to %3A, then the cflogin.password works!

Comment: As far as the ColdFusion newbie I am can see, `<cflogin>` is responsible for checking if the login/password pair supplied is right, so I don't know either what ColdFusion does with the password from `<cfloginuser>`. Also, NTLM was made specifically to be passwordless.

Comment: Ray's blog has changed. Find the CFLOGIN-Bug article under https://web.archive.org/web/20121103025256/https://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/8/7/Watch-out-for-this-CFLOGIN-Bug