# Starting a Session and assigning a unique session ID in Coldfusion

Tags: session, cookies, coldfusion

I have done some very basic authentication work in PHP. In PHP you can start a session and create a unique session ID to be stored in the cookies.

How does this work in ColdFusion? How can I start a session and assign a unique ID to it?

The backstory: I am trying to a create a log in page, I can create users and authenticate their login attempts but I need to know how to give them a unique session once they have logged in.

I've  taken a look at the ColdFusion documentation. The only methods I could find for sessions seemed to be for browsers that don't use cookies for whatever reason. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, if in your application.cfm or application.cfc you set SessionManagement to 'true' then CF automatically creates a session for each new user. You can then set a property of the session (perhaps called 'loggedin') to be true or false to manage login state. Session duration is managed through the SessionTimeout property in application.cfc

You can also use the `<cfloginuser>` tag to manage whether a user is logged in, [although some people avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604909/why-dont-people-use-cflogin)

Take a look at [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-Tutorial-And-Application-cfc-Reference.htm) for an overview of application.cfc

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer, bonus points for saying how to check whether the user is logged in.